# Op-amp subtractor circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider, voltage-measurement, differential-amplifier

While using Op-amp as a subtractor circuit the input applied to inverting and noninverting terminals are generally referenced to the DC ground of the circuit as shown in the picture below.
[image: Op-amp Subtractor circuit]
Pic credit: [Electronics Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html)

I want to ask if I've to measure the 220V(rms),50Hz ac voltage using a voltage divider circuit as shown below
[image: Voltage Divider Circuit]

Is it safe to assume V_ph and N_in will be referenced to the DC ground here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are dealing with mains power, I'll make the usual disclaimer: if you hurt yourself or anyone else, or set fire to something as a result of anything you read here, that's on you, and I accept no responsibility.

By drawing the Thevenin equivalent of the source of signal between V_ph and N_in, we immediately get some pointers:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc2AEu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R7 attenuates the signal by a factor of 1000, but in this configuration it also adds source impedance Rth to one side only, which will change the input-output relationship, and crucially, offset the output from zero-mean.

Attenuation could be performed by the differential amplifier itself:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faDG7z.png)</sup>

This is exactly like the reference differential amplifier, why no extraneous impedances anywhere to mess with gain or offset. Here we have exactly \$V_{OUT} = \frac{PH_{IN} - N_{IN}}{1000}\$.

Of course, R8 and R9 should consist of several lower value resistors in series, a good idea that you implemented with R1...R5. Now, though, R8 and R9 form the input resistances, and both should employ this technique.

With R7 absent, we now rely on R8 and R6 to attenuate phase potential, and R9 and R10 to attenuate neutral potential. This provides a nice balanced pair of input resistances which treat phase and neutral equally, allowing you to even swap them, with no change in behaviour (except a signal inversion).

I have reduced gain to \$\frac{1}{1000}\$ by choosing \$R_6 = R_{10} = \frac{R_8}{1000}\$, while making R10 a suitable value for an op-amp output to drive. 1MΩ feedback is too large (susceptible to noise and interference), and 1kΩ requires current close to the maximum that a typical op-amp output can source or sink.

In this configuration, the two op-amp inputs P and Q will never exceed +680mV, or drop below -680mV, regardless of the potential of phase or neutral with respect to the op-amp's own ground. They will remain within the op-amp's acceptable input voltage range.

This circuit has gain of exactly \$\frac{1}{1000}\$, has balanced input impedances to avoid a signal offset from zero-mean. Op-amp input voltage range is never violated, regardless of which input is closer in potential to your op-amp's own ground.

Comment: Sir, for the op-amp circuit with smaller resistances(of order few Kohms) Thevenin's resistance will pose a problem, it is clear. But for the circuit, I have mentioned above will it be even significant?

Comment: @Satya 1k out out 1M is only 0.1% error, so it's not a big problem. The problem is the common mode potential that you expose the op-amp inputs to, because of difference in grounds. To solve this ***requires*** that you have a large resistance in the neutral path too. And if you do that, then R7 is completely redundant, and you might as well just attenuate with the diff. amp, as I have shown.

Comment: You usually will want to stay away from attenuating with a difference amplifier. The lower the gain, the worse the common-mode rejection will be due to resistor matching. Assuming a perfect op amp, CMRR = (A+1)/(4*t), where t == resitor tolerance: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/deeper-look-into-difference-amplifiers.html

Comment: @sbell Thank you for the reference material. It's a great help. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the 220V is the AC mains supply, Neutral is typically connected to Earth somewhere but there will be a small voltage difference.  In fault conditions there might be a significant voltage and so your circuit should (at least) tolerate this.  Making any DC connection between Neutral and Earth inside equipment is very much frowned upon in most electrical standards.  An exception to this might be in something like a lighting dimmer where the nominal ‘ground’ is not connected to Earth but is isolated and properly insulated against contact from anything external to the equipment.  But in most cases you’ll want a transformer to isolate the AC supply from your low-voltage DC.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it safe to assume - ?

No.

1. Not without a lot of information about whatever power supply is providing the DC power to the circuit.  Some supplies have a direct or optional connection between the supply's output GND (such as the +5 V Return) and the supply's chassis or earth ground input connection.  Without knowing the relationship between earth ground and the system's circuit GND, you are courting danger.
2. Even if the supply's output is referenced to earth, there is no guarantee that the incoming neutral is at the same potential.
3. Even if it is, connecting the secondary of an isolated supply to either side of the incoming mains defeats *all* of the safety features of the power transformer.

I'm not saying it never is done, or is guaranteed lethal.  There are a lot of products in the world that do in fact have non-isolated, offline power systems.  But these products almost always have extra layers of insulation, some other form of energy limiting, and much more difficult certification agency testing.  For an experienced designer, this is just another day at the office.  For someone asking your question, I'd guess that it is beyond your skill set.

There are other methods.  What is it your are trying to achieve?

UPDATE:  Now that you have revealed that you are using the RPi supply (probably a wall wart, but I've not seen one), then your circuit should work.  It will "float" on the incoming mains no matter which way it is connected.  But there still is a huge safety risk, as anything else that is connected to the pi now ***will not be isolated from the mains.***  This could be the shaft of a pot, a connector shell, a pushbutton frame, etc; and of course, any interconnect wires and component pins.

Comment: The DC Power is being supplied by a Raspberry Pi using +5V and GND pins of the board. -5V is being produced using a charge pump IC w.r.t same GND. Let's say DC GND is at 0V, then even if neutral isn't at the same potential as GND the subtractor circuit should take care of it as phase voltage can be written as Vph= Vn+V(R7). Am I right about this conclusion?

Comment: Correct.  But - where does the power from the RPi come from?  Is that source fully isolated from the AC mains?

Comment: Sir, I'm using the official Raspberry Pi power adapter to supply the power to RPi.

Comment: Can you check your update.  "will be isolated from the mains", shouldn't be the exact opposite?

Comment: Writing while recovering from anesthetic.  oops.  fixed.  thanks.

Comment: @AnalogKid Thanks for your update.